# Joomla doesn't show modules

Tags: joomla-module, joomla3.1

I use Joomla 3.10.11. I have made a few modules and used the yoo-master2 for positions. I have the exact same settings, template and positions on everything as my classmates but my site doesn't show anything for some reason. Even my teacher is clueless. Is there anything I can do that may solve this?

Comment: Please see [ask] and take the [tour]. Your question needs improvement.

Comment: Check Joomla cache and browser cache. Also check page assignment.

Comment: As this isn't a code question you might do better at https://joomla.stackexchange.com.